# How to keep the slider of MPVolumeView visible when connecting to Apple TV?

Tags: objective-c, mpvolumeview

I'm using an MPVolumeView to control the volume of the AVPlayer in my app.
When I connect use the Airplay-button next to the volume slider to connect to an AppleTV, the slider disappears. How can this be avoided?

When I use the Music app to stream music to the same AppleTV the volume slider in the music app stays visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to set `allowsExternalPlayback` to NO on the AVPlayer:

```
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:self.streamUrl];
self.player.allowsExternalPlayback = NO;
```

Comment: I don't know why and I didn't believe your code until I try. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation.  My fix was:

```
player.allowsAirPlayVideo = NO; // keeps volume slider from disappearing
```